# Cloud Shell idle cpu usage seems relatively high (3-6%) - where is this usage coming from?

Tags: cpu-usage, google-cloud

```
top - 12:10:09 up  2:18,  6 users,  load average: 0.03, 0.03, 0.00
Tasks:  35 total,   1 running,  34 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.1 us,  1.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  1735912 total,   437708 free,   378916 used,   919288 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.  1188436 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                            
  251 alan_ch+  20   0  636432  12428   6504 S  0.2  0.7   0:02.46 python         
    1 root      20   0   17980   2800   2496 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.01 bash           
    8 root      20   0  250120   2212   1776 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.84 rsyslogd
   38 root      20   0   69952   3040   2268 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 sshd
```

Google Cloud includes [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/quickstart).  This provides an interactive Linux sandbox, which can be used for light administration or testing tasks.  It is available without payment or payment information.  *Terms and conditions apply*.

The summary CPU usage in `top` consistently shows as around 3-6%, even after increasing the interval (`top -d 10`).  But, the if you look at the CPU usage shown for the individual processes, it doesn't add up.

What is using the CPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current Cloud Shell creates a private VM, for maximum flexibility.  But the actual shell it shows you is running inside a container.  The container is very privileged, but since it uses a separate PID namespace you cannot see the processes outside the container.

```
$ amicontained
Container Runtime: kube
Has Namespaces:
        pid: true
        user: false
AppArmor Profile: unconfined
Capabilities:
        BOUNDING -> chown dac_override dac_read_search fowner fsetid kill setgid setuid setpcap linux_immutable net_bind_service net_broadcast net_admin net_raw ipc_lock ipc_owner sys_module sys_rawio sys_chroot sys_ptrace sys_pacct sys_admin sys_boot sys_nice sys_resource sys_time sys_tty_config mknod lease audit_write audit_control setfcap mac_override mac_admin syslog wake_alarm block_suspend audit_read
Chroot (not pivot_root): false
Seccomp: disabled
```

Privileged containers can be [escaped](https://www.nccgroup.trust/globalassets/our-research/us/whitepapers/2016/june/container_whitepaper.pdf), using a few carefully crafted shell commands.  This is not a security exploit, it's just not the intended use.   (Do not abuse the Cloud Shell resources.  You can trust that *Google* know something about monitoring resource usage of virtual machines).

E.g. I was able to mount devtmpfs, create some pipes, leverage `core_pattern` to open a shell on `/dev/fifo_in` / `/dev/fifo_out`.  Inside the shell, I re-entered the containers *mount* namespace only.  Then it is sufficient to over-mount /proc with a new procfs mount.  With that, I could open `top` in another Cloud Shell tab, and it would show the *host* PID namespace.

Let's say they haven't (yet) optimized the idle resource usage.

```
top - 12:50:14 up  2:58,  3 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.05, 0.04
Tasks: 127 total,   1 running,  96 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s):  3.1 us,  1.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 95.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  1735912 total,   444240 free,   351448 used,   940224 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.  1215836 avail Mem

USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                  
root      20   0  413140  58704  26008 S  2.7  3.4   4:31.18 kubelet      
root      20   0  378940  46260  15912 S  0.6  2.7   1:03.18 dockerd                                                                  
root      20   0  184008   9760   5408 S  0.1  0.6   0:14.27 python         
alan_ch+  20   0  644372  12392   6584 S  0.1  0.7   0:00.07 python         
root      20   0   66364  33976  33472 S  0.1  2.0   0:10.34 systemd-journal   
root      20   0  292264  22488  13616 S  0.1  1.3   0:04.56 docker-containe   
root      20   0  369808  64224  36928 S  0.1  3.7   0:03.81 dockerd          
root      20   0  365684   6408   3668 S  0.1  0.4   0:06.00 docker-containe
alan_ch+  20   0   58060  20272   7560 S  0.0  1.2   0:01.27 python                                                                   
root      20   0       0      0      0 I  0.0  0.0   0:04.42 rcu_sched
```